# Sync between the Content DB and Profile DB is not happening?

Tags: user-profile, stsadm, user-profile-service

Sync between the Content DB and Profile DB is not happening since a week, even the command "`stsadm -o sync -DeleteOldDatabases 0"` is failed to respond. is there any other specific command can be used here?

Comment: Needs to be run as the farm account.

Answer (score 4):

'A failure occurred during the processing of this command. Check diagnostic logs for more information' is in fact "Access Denied error to the User Profile Service Application".

> TO resolve this issue, Navigate to  Manage Service Applications ---> 
>   User Profile Service Application Name ---->  select Permissions from
>   the ribbon ---->   Add your user account with full control right.

Retry the `stsadm.exe -o sync -deleteolddatabases` command. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

What method are you using to verify whether the sync is working or not?  Are you looking at the timer jobs and see that they aren't running?  Are you just looking at one person and seeing their data isn't correct?  Etc.

In the past I've seen this happen when someone is just looking at someone's data and typically this is after the person's userid (samaccountname) has changed.  Then we usually run migrateuser to clear it up.

Sometimes I've seen it when a database or site collection is readonly, or over it's quota, that can affect the sync and the migrateuser command.

Comment: I've actually used the standard sharepoint command - stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0. 

Its returns that none of my content db synced since a week. 

So decided to run the command stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0 however it was running for half an hour without any result so i stopped it in the middle. 

I have even tried with stsadm -o sync -synctiming M:2 and waited for an hour but still content dbs are not in sync with the profile db. 

any help?

Answer (score 0):

If the content DB is set to offline, the profile data does not get synced I seem to recall.  If that is the case, you'll want to set the content DB to ready, but also set the max number of sites to the current number of sites so no new ones will be created.

Comment: all of the dbs are in ready state.